# Move image in QGraphicsView second per second

Tags: c++, qt, qthread, qtcore, qtimer

I'm trying to move one image in a QGraphicsView every second, I tried four methods, but none of them worked for me.

1) I used QTest, using the function QTest::qSleep() but this didn't work at all, cause two errors appear in the application, I think have to be with the .pro file of the project.

2) I used QThread in my second try, QThread::sleep() at least, the application run, but the image is already in the last position I set before. I mean, the sleep is not working(Works some times, but in a different way, once the loop is done and the sleep worked inside the loop, the Application some times appear in the screen. Sometimes Freeze and don't show the App.)

3) I used one function that a user post in other question, he said is an alternative to the Sleep function.

```
QTime dieTime= QTime::currentTime().addSecs(1);
while( QTime::currentTime() < dieTime )
QCoreApplication::processEvents(QEventLoop::AllEvents, 100);
```

4) I used QWaitCondition too, this is one alternative like the other option.

```
QMutex dummy;
dummy.lock();
QWaitCondition waitCondition;
waitCondition.wait(&dummy, waitTime);
```

I read something about QTimer, but I don't know how to use it yet, I'm a beginner in QT, I just know the basics.
All I tried I did inside the while loop.

The Code where I need to implement this:

```
void Window::start(PilaD *caminoGato,PilaD *caminoRaton){
 /*
 YOU DONT NEED TO UNDERSTAND THIS CODE
 Nodo *recorGato,*recorRaton;
 recorGato = new Nodo();
 recorRaton = new Nodo();
 recorGato = caminoGato->tope;
 recorRaton = caminoRaton->tope;
 By The Way, for you to understand, recorGato is a class, this class have two variable row and col
 */


 QPixmap *icon = new QPixmap(list.at(2));
 QGraphicsPixmapItem *gato = new QGraphicsPixmapItem(*icon);
 scene->addItem(gato);

 while(recorGato!=NULL){
    //ALL I TRIED, I PLACE IT HERE, INSIDE THE LOOP
    gato->setPos(recorGato->col*icon->width()+200,recorGato->row*icon->height()+100);
    recorGato = recorGato->pre;
 }
}
```

The thing is that every time a second pass, the image on the frame, move to the next position until he reach a limit, and stop moving. I don't know if making a delay is the best way, but I need to move the image every second, the way doesn't matter. Thanks for Reading.

Answer (score 0):

try using QTimer with a slot. I am writing a sudo code only.

```
void MyClass::myFunc()
{
    mTimer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(slotMoveImage()));
    mTimer->start(1000); // set timeout for 1 second
 }


/***Slot will look something like this**/

void MyClass::slotMoveImage()
{
 // Move image and restart the timer. Do not restart if we don't want to move further
  img->setPos(img.rect().x() + 200, img.rect.y()+100);
  if(/* not some condition */)
     mTimer->start(1000); // again start the timer
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit difficult to understand why certain parts of your previous trials have not worked as you have not shared much details.

As for using `QTimer`, I would read the [official documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QTimer.html#details) about it. It gives you pretty good and probably the most authoritative answer.

Here is the gist inline for your convenience:

> Example for a one second (1000 millisecond) timer (from the Analog Clock example):

```
    QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(update()));
    timer->start(1000);
```

> From then on, the update() slot is called every second.

This will provide you an async (i.e. non-blocking) solution as opposed to the previous "sleep" operations. This way, your code remains responsive unlike with sleep.

Answer (score 0):

Please use QTimeLine - this is the way to go.